# im using reactnative and cant upload voice to nodejs using multer

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

this is how i send the file to the backend server from expo running on physical device

```
const sendtoserver = async (cfileurl) => {
        try {
        
          const vform = new FormData().append("voice", { uri: cfileurl });
          const r = await fetch("http://192.168.10.20:3001/file", {
            method: "POST",
            body: vform,
          });
          const body = await r.json();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("error", e);
        }
      };
```

below is how i parse it on nodejs

```
const app = require("express")();
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "uploads/", // Specify the directory where you want to store the uploaded files
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.get("/file", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("voice here");
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Reached" });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Failure" });
  }
});
app.post("/file", upload.single("voice"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("post voice here", req.body);
    console.log("d", req.file);

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Reached" });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Failure" });
  }
});
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Im listening");
});
```

However i get undefined when i log the req.file and also no file is uploaded to uploads

Comment: `cfileurl` seems to be file reference `file://path/to/file`. You should upload  audio raw data like `blob` or `base64`